# Where are "supercompressors" used in the "real world"?

Tags: compression

I'm testing some "supercompressors" (PAQ8, PPMd, etc.) for academic purposes, and was wondering if they're used in some "real world" context. They are much much more expensive in terms of speed and memory than other common compressors (gzip, bzip2, 7zip, etc.), and the compression they achieve doesn't seem to justify the saving in bandwidth for transmission, for example.

Far from me to criticize these awesome pieces of software. [PAQ8](https://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/#paq), for example, can compress basically any kind of file (text, images, executables) given that it uses several simultaneous models and mixes their predictions to achieve its impressive compression ratio.

Comment: This question was voted as "too broad", but I don't believe that asking for usage examples would need long answers. A simple "We use compressor <X> for <Y> application because of <Z>" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Greetings, you should take a look on SuperUser. I think this is why it was flagued off-topic. Your question is not about straight coding but about program performance ... and, also, on first look, you just have a link to PAQ8 wich might scare people for 'specific product advertisement' perception.

Comment: Ok, I'll cross-post there. And 'product advertising' was definitely not my intention!

Answer (score 1):

For backup its nice to have some options. Freearc is also very good. Srep, Deduplication and Lzma is also better.